# Why isn't footer 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I'm expecting my footer to occupy all horizontal space at the bottom of the page, `width 100%` BUt for some reason it is centred in page and seems to have characteristics of my wrapper.
Here is image (Website is not live yet so I can't provide a link)

[image]

That black footer should occupy all horizontal space at the bottom, I'll include code which I think is responsible for this issue (code simplified, so will be different from image).

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aHpua/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
            <article class="content-info">Content
            </article>
            <aside class="sidebar">
                <h4>MORE INFORMATION</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
    </div><!-- END.content-wrapper -->
    <div class="contact-us">
        <h2>
            Have any questions for us?
            <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </h2>
    </div><!-- END.contact-us -->
<div class="footer-container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <footer class="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li>Tel:<span> 0000</span></li>
                    <li>Fax:<span> 0000</span></li>
                    <li>Email: <a href="mailto:nla@bla.com">bla</a></li>
                    <li><h1>Company Name</h1></li>
                </ul> 
            </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- END.footer-wrapper -->
        <div class="copyright">
            <div class="wrapper">
                &copy; Copyright 2013.
            </div><!-- END.copyright-wrapper -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- END.footer-container -->    
        <?php wp_footer(); ?>
       <!-- Google Analytics --> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* ==========================================================================
   =content
   ========================================================================== */

.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    padding: 30px 65px 30px 65px;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #ffffff inset,
                0 -2px 0 #ebebeb inset,
                0 -3px 0 #ffffff inset,
                0 -4px 0 #efefef inset;
}

.contact-us {
    background-color: #f9faf6;
    padding: 30px 65px 30px 65px;
    border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -5px #d3d3d3 inset;
    clear: both;
}

.content-info {
    float: left;
    width: 590px;
    background: red;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 220px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   =footer
   ========================================================================== */


.footer-container {
    background-color: #2a2a2b;
    background-image: url(img/header_bg.png);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    border-top: 5px solid #00b2e5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.copyright {
    background-color: #242424;
    color: #6b6b6b;
    width: 100%;
}

.copyright .wrapper {
    padding: 7px 65px 7px 65px;
    width: 850px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you posted. Why don't you at least *try* to narrow it down. We don't need stuff like `box-shadow` or `Have any questions for us?` to debug this issue. This is what's called "debugging", simplifying your problem until you can identify the cause.

Comment: I would start by stripping all the css references from your tags and re-adding them one at the time to see which one prevents the footer from display the way you wanted it.

Comment: Please post the complete html. this is only one half

Comment: With a jsfiddle we could help you in just 1 `F12` press ;)

Comment: @Bondye Here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/aHpua/4/

Comment: @s.lenders I posted jsfiddle with full code

Comment: Ok, your wrapper has a width, and your footer's 100% is your wrappers width.

Comment: @Bondye I don't get it, wrapper is supposed to be inside footer, let me go through code again

Comment: You have also a wrapper after `header-container-element`. Hint: `try to press f12 and understand the developers tool ;)`

Comment: Ok I was missing a closing div tag Thank you everyone ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.wrapper {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The object is inside of a .wrapper

Answer (score 4):

from what I see it's a wordpress theme.make sure your footer is not inside #page which has fixed width and margin 0 auto.

that div starts in the header.php and ends in footer.php.

make sure your code validates and you don't have unclosed div's. if you have #page in the header, close it before footer

Answer (score 2):

It appears that .content, .footer-container etc. must have a common parent somewhere that has a fixed width. width: 100% will only make the footer as wide as that parent, not wider, so you have to move it outside.